# Calling Elastica class using "_" instead of "\"

Tags: php, symfony, elastica

I'm using Elastica search engine for my Symfony project.

Now, I'm getting the below error :

> The autoloader expected class "Elastica_Query_Bool" to be defined in
>   file
>   "/blablabla/vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Query/Bool.php".
>   The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or
>   namespace probably has a typo.

If I change `new \Elastica_Query_Bool()` for `new \Elastica\Query\Bool()` in my php file, it works fine.

But I can't understand why I'm getting an error now. Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when you new Elastica_Query_Bool it's looking for a class actually called Elastica_Query_Bool.  And of course the actual class is called Bool.

try:

```
use Elastica\Query\Bool; // At the top of your file following the namespace line.
...
$bool = new Bool();
```

Might want to review namespaces in the php manual.

Comment: Yeah sure, it's looking for this class and it does not exist but it worked before. More, all the examples I can find on Elastica suggest to use new Elastica_Query_Bool(). So maybe something change in Elastica bundle or in a newest version of Symfony ?

Comment: Check the Bool.php file.  Does it have a namespace deceleration?  If it does then it means it has been upgraded from a pre=namespace version.  You must be looking at old examples.

Comment: This article might help: http://richardmiller.co.uk/2011/11/11/symfony2-integrating-elasticsearch/

Comment: I've just had a look to the history of the file `Bool.php` in `https://github.com/ruflin/Elastica/` repository, and this commit `https://github.com/ruflin/Elastica/commit/94b4b8ac854fafefaad5b51831094d34f9b4ebfd` introduced the use of namespace. So, no more "_" (like the other bundles) and I have my answer :) By the way, your answer is correct (even if it does not really fit to my question).